# Is it possible to create a reference Surface Pro 3 with all the required software and capture to be deploy to 15 Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, microsoft-surface

I just got 15 Surface Pro 3 from our client.  They would like me to configure the tablets with the standard softwares for all of the systems.
The tablet already has the Windows 8.1.
I have configure the system with all of the softwares.  Now I am trying to figure out how I can create a image of this tablet and deploy it to 15 other Surface Pro 3.

Comment: You can do this the same way you would for any other OS deployment... using SCCM, MDT, or whatever imaging software you usually use. Do you have an existing OS deployment platform?

Answer (score 0):

It’s never really recommended to create an image from a fully configured system. The recommended route would be to create your base image in a VM, devoid of potential driver conflicts and installed software, then use a deployment solution like MDT or SCCM to manage drivers and applications during deployment. You should really check out the [Surface Pro 3 Deployment and Administration Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45292).

With that said, you can certainly capture an image from one and deploy it to others. If you are using the network/PXE you will need the Surface Ethernet Adapter or Docking Station for PXE support. If you are using a USB stick you will need FAT32 for UEFI support. A common issue with USB support is that your captured WIM may be over 4GB, especially for a fat image like yours complete with software and configuration. [There is a documented workaround here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/20/creating-bootable-usb-drive-for-uefi-computers.aspx).